# the connectionstring property has not been initialized in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Everytime I click the button where the sub procedure execute, I'm getting the error "the connection string property has not been initialized"

Here is my code

```
Sub CheckExistingExp()
        Dim aexpcheckifexisting As New DataSet
        Dim bexpcheckifexisting As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim sqlcheck As String
        Dim duplicateexp As Integer
        sqlcheck = "select count(exp_doc) vcount from csap_exph where exp_doc = '" & RQuote(txtExpDoc.Text) & "' and status = 'A'"
        bexpcheckifexisting = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcheck, con)
        bexpcheckifexisting.Fill(aexpcheckifexisting, "checkduplicateexp")
        duplicateexp = aexpcheckifexisting.Tables("checkduplicateexp").Rows(0).Item("vcount")
        If duplicateexp > 0 Then
            If MsgBox("Expense Doc is already existing, are you sure you want to tag it as posted?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                Approve_Expense()
            Else
                con.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

What should I do to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to initialise connection string like :
Dim Connection As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=xxxx;Integrated
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

Comment: Let alone the connection string which is missing, where did you open con for you to close it? [con.open()]

Comment: Hi @MertAkkanat, I initialise the connection string in the module. What should I do after?

Comment: Hi @Devcon, I don't get it. Sorry, I'm just a beginner here in .net. Thanks

Comment: @Lawrencxe you need to open connection in method, then use it to connect database. Here is an example : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/343216/vb-net-db-connection

Answer (score 0):

Let alone the connection string which is missing, where did you open con for you to close it? [con.open()] and if your user hits MsgBoxResult.Yes your connection would stay open cause con.Close() is only called if duplicateexp <= 0.
dispose your con at the end of your code or use `using` which closes it automatically and use a try-catch to catch any errors.
have your connection string somewhere in app.config or make it public in a class or module or whatever you prefer and make your string = that value and open your connection at the beginning of the sub.

Comment: Instead of manually managing conn.Dispose in an error construct, your answer should recommend `Using`

Comment: Everytime i answer a beginner i try to put lots of hints in there but yeah, whatever works for him

Comment: @Devcon I guess the beginner could tell you that the `.Fill` method of a `DataAdapter` open and closes the connection.